# How will we get area Chart with Close values for highstock instead of open values when i pass the series data as 'ohlc'?

Tags: jquery, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

```
series: [{
                    type: '<%=m_sType %>',
                    name: 'Stock Price',
                    id: 'dataseries',
                    data: (function () { 
                            var success = area;
                            $('.chartType').click(function() {
                                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                                if(href == '#CandleStick' || href == '#OHLC'){
                                  success = ohlc;
                                }
                                else{
                                  success = area;
                                }
                            });
                            return success;
                    }()),
                    dataGrouping: {
                        units: groupingUnits
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 3 
                    },
                    threshold: null
                    },{
                    type: 'column',
                    name: 'Volume',
                    data: volume,
                    yAxis: 1,
                    dataGrouping: {
                        units: groupingUnits
                    }
                }]
```

i am trying to change the data with area array which contains date and close values but it is also not working.

Comment: How your data does it look like ?

Comment: ohlc data Array is like DAY,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE same as you data file for highstock. Volume data array contains    DAY,VOLUME.In area array i used to pass  DAY,CLOSE.based on chart clicks it have to change @SebastianBochan

Comment: Could you paste your JSON here?